# Convert string to Enum in Python

Tags: python, string, enums, type-conversion

What's the correct way to convert a string to a corresponding instance of an `Enum` subclass? Seems like `getattr(YourEnumType, str)` does the job, but I'm not sure if it's safe enough.

As an example, suppose I have an enum like

```
class BuildType(Enum):
    debug = 200
    release = 400
```

Given the string `'debug'`, how can I get `BuildType.debug` as a result?

Comment: Contra the original version of the question, this is **not** a "serialization" task.

Answer (score 582, accepted):

This functionality is already built in to [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes):

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Build(Enum):
...   debug = 200
...   build = 400
... 
>>> Build['debug']
<Build.debug: 200>
```

The member names are case sensitive, so if user-input is being converted you need to make sure case matches:

```
an_enum = input('Which type of build?')
build_type = Build[an_enum.lower()]
```

Comment: What about a fallback value in case the input needs to be sanitised? Something in the sort of `Build.get('illegal', Build.debug)`?

Comment: @Hetzroni:  `Enum` does not come with a `.get()` method, but you can add one as needed, or just make a base `Enum` class and always inherit from that.

Comment: @Hetzroni: Per the "ask for forgiveness, not for permission" principle, you can always envelop the access in a try/except KeyError clause to return the default (and as Ethan mentioned, optionally wrap this up in your own function/method).

Comment: Worth noting here - if using this for serialization / deserialization, serialize the `name` property for this, so use `Build.debug.name` rather than `str(Build.debug)` for this sort of lookup to work (otherwise it tries to find `Build.debug` on the deserialization side which won't exist).

Comment: @Dragonborn It wouldn't work to call `Build('debug')`. The class constructor must take the *value*, i.e. `200` or `400` in this example. To pass the *name* you must use square brackets, as the answer already says.

Comment: It's worth noting that common case is to have enums with values equal the labels, like `debug = 'debug'`. In such cases getting an enum value by `Build('debug')` is preferred over `Build['debug']` as it raises a `ValueError` in case of an incorrect value (instead of a `KeyError`).

Answer (score 48):

Another alternative (especially useful if your strings don't map 1-1 to your enum cases) is to add a `staticmethod` to your `Enum`, e.g.:

```
class QuestionType(enum.Enum):
    MULTI_SELECT = "multi"
    SINGLE_SELECT = "single"

    @staticmethod
    def from_str(label):
        if label in ('single', 'singleSelect'):
            return QuestionType.SINGLE_SELECT
        elif label in ('multi', 'multiSelect'):
            return QuestionType.MULTI_SELECT
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
```

Then you can do `question_type = QuestionType.from_str('singleSelect')`

Comment: Is there any way to overwrite the `__getitem__` or some other built-in method?

Comment: I think the compiler or at least Pycharm thinks the from_str function is returning a str type. Using QuestionType["some_string"], as described in a different answer, has Pycharm thinking its a QuestionType type

Comment: @ClementWalter yes, but since it needs to be implemented *on the enum type itself, not on instances*, you need to do it in a metaclass. The thing is - `enum.Enum` *already does this for you*. You *could* subclass `enum.Enum`'s metaclass, which is also exposed as `enum.EnumType`, and override its `__getitem__` - but do you actually need it to do something different from the default?

Answer (score 17):

```
def custom_enum(typename, items_dict):
    class_definition = """
from enum import Enum

class {}(Enum):
    {}""".format(typename, '\n    '.join(['{} = {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in items_dict.items()]))

    namespace = dict(__name__='enum_%s' % typename)
    exec(class_definition, namespace)
    result = namespace[typename]
    result._source = class_definition
    return result

MyEnum = custom_enum('MyEnum', {'a': 123, 'b': 321})
print(MyEnum.a, MyEnum.b)
```

Or do you need to convert string to **known** Enum?

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    a = 'aaa'
    b = 123

print(MyEnum('aaa'), MyEnum(123))
```

Or:

```
class BuildType(Enum):
    debug = 200
    release = 400

print(BuildType.__dict__['debug'])

print(eval('BuildType.debug'))
print(type(eval('BuildType.debug')))    
print(eval(BuildType.__name__ + '.debug'))  # for work with code refactoring
```

Comment: I mean I would like to convert a `debug` string to an enum of such:

```python
class BuildType(Enum):
    debug = 200
    release = 400
```

Comment: Great tips! Is using `__dict__` the same as `getattr`? I'm worrying about name collisions with internal Python attributes....

Comment: Oh... yes it the same as `getattr`. I see no reason for name collisions. You just can't set keyword as field of class.

Answer (score 14):

My Java-like solution to the problem. Hope it helps someone...

```py
from enum import Enum, auto


class SignInMethod(Enum):
    EMAIL = auto(),
    GOOGLE = auto()

    @classmethod
    def value_of(cls, value):
        for k, v in cls.__members__.items():
            if k == value:
                return v
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"'{cls.__name__}' enum not found for '{value}'")


sim = SignInMethod.value_of('EMAIL')
assert sim == SignInMethod.EMAIL
assert sim.name == 'EMAIL'
assert isinstance(sim, SignInMethod)
# SignInMethod.value_of("invalid sign-in method")  # should raise `ValueError`
```

Comment: Today, do `SignInMethod('EMAIL')` had the same effect which that method

Answer (score 4):

In [Python 3.11 you could also use a `StrEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum). Granted, you would have to replace the values with strings as well, since it keyes on the value, not name (using [`enum.auto()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#enum.auto) for the value is an ok solution).

```py
import enum

class BuildType(enum.StrEnum):
    debug = "200"
    release = "400"

print(BuildType("debug"))
```

Comment: Very important to note that StrEnum.__getitem__() does NOT work like Enum.__getitem__() so for a StrEnum using `BuildType["debug"]` will always result in a KeyError and you have to use the syntax you've shown here with `BuildType("debug")` instead.  This is exactly the opposite of an regular Enum that was assigned strings as the values.

Answer (score 3):

```
class LogLevel(IntEnum):
    critical = logging.CRITICAL
    fatal = logging.FATAL
    error = logging.ERROR
    warning = logging.WARNING
    info = logging.INFO
    debug = logging.DEBUG
    notset = logging.NOTSET

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}.{self.name}'

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        if type(value) is str:
            value = value.lower()
            if value in dir(cls):
                return cls[value]

        raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
```

Example:

```
print(LogLevel('Info'))
print(LogLevel(logging.WARNING))
print(LogLevel(10))    # logging.DEBUG
print(LogLevel.fatal)
print(LogLevel(550))
```

Output:

```
LogLevel.info
LogLevel.warning
LogLevel.debug
LogLevel.critical
ValueError: 550 is not a valid LogLevel
```

Comment: wow, a rare _sunder_.  This answer has the benefit of being "drop in", and thus works with existing "structuring" libraries, in my case cattrs, without any customization.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An improvement to the answer of @rogueleaderr :

```
class QuestionType(enum.Enum):
    MULTI_SELECT = "multi"
    SINGLE_SELECT = "single"

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, label):
        if label in ('single', 'singleSelect'):
            return cls.SINGLE_SELECT
        elif label in ('multi', 'multiSelect'):
            return cls.MULTI_SELECT
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `MyEnum['dontexist']` will result in error `KeyError: 'dontexist'`, you might like to fail silently (eg. return None). In such case you can use the following static method:

```
class Statuses(enum.Enum):
    Unassigned = 1
    Assigned = 2

    @staticmethod
    def from_str(text):
        statuses = [status for status in dir(
            Statuses) if not status.startswith('_')]
        if text in statuses:
            return getattr(Statuses, text)
        return None


Statuses.from_str('Unassigned')
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your class signature to this:

```py
class BuildType(str, Enum):
```

See [`enum` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#notes)

Comment: Could you add more detail? How would one then use the class?

Comment: The author did not further clarify. When you declare your class in this fashion, you can use the enum string values to create direct instances of the enum value. you can have A = "FIRST_VALUE" - then doing BuildType("FIRST_VALUE") will get you BuildType.A automatically. It only applies to your use case if the string values are the same as the enum name

Answer (score 0):

##### Getting enum instance by name

If you want to access enum members by name, use item access:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Build(Enum):
...   debug = 200
...   build = 400
... 
>>> Build['debug']
<Build.debug: 200>
```

It raises `KeyError` for unexpected name value.

##### Getting enum instance by value

For following Enum class, where the values are strings:

```
class BuildType(Enum):
    debug = 'debug'
    release = 'release'
```

An enumeration uses call syntax to return members by value:

```
>>> BuildType('debug')
<BuildType.debug: 'debug'>
```

It raises `ValueError` for unexpected value.