# Get Enum Member by user input in Python

Tags: python-3.x, enums

I want to take `ENUM member` from user input. Till now I have found where I have to do this as hard code or y using the `ENUM member value`.

**Example code which works**
[code reference](https://zetcode.com/python/enum/)

```
from enum import Enum

class Season(Enum):
    SPRING = 1
    SUMMER = 2
    AUTUMN = 3
    WINTER = 4


seas = Season.SPRING
print(seas)
```

**Example code which I want to execute**

```
from enum import Enum

class Season(Enum):
    SPRING = 1
    SUMMER = 2
    AUTUMN = 3
    WINTER = 4

print("Give the User Input\n")
x = input() # user will write SPRING
seas_x = Season.x
print(seas_x)
```

I know the former one will not work as I am passing a string type variable to `Season` ENUM which has no member of that type/name. But is there any workaround to achieve it? For some restrictions, I have to use the `ENUM member name` as user input.

Comment: You could use `Season[x]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to Enum in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407414/convert-string-to-enum-in-python)

Comment: @Heike thanks. It is working. Though it is still throwing me an Error which is another issue regarding `pybind11`. 
@FlorianGD yes. I have mistakenly `submit NO` in your suggestion.