# Get enum value from string variable?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the enum:

```
class Example(Enum):
    a = "example1"
    b = "example2"
val = "a"
# print(Example.val.value) (?)
```

How can I get an enum value from a string using val? In my actual code, I need to do something like this because the name is unknown, and I need to access it from a string assigned to a variable.

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/41407414/843953

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `Example[val].value`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes

[Convert string to Enum in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407414/convert-string-to-enum-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets:

```
from enum import Enum


class Example(Enum):
    a = "example1"
    b = "example2"


def main() -> None:
    val = "a"
    print(f"{val = }")
    print(f"{Example[val] = }")
    print(f"{Example[val].value = }")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
val = 'a'
Example[val] = <Example.a: 'example1'>
Example[val].value = 'example1'
```